# Verilog code does not print desired output

Tags: verilog

Can you tell me why this simple verilog program doesn't print 4 as I want?

```
primitive confrontatore(output z, input x, input y);

 table
   0 0 : 1; 
   0 1 : 0; 
   1 0 : 0;
   1 1 : 1;
 endtable 

endprimitive
```

comparatore :

```
module comparatore (r, x, y); 

   output wire r;
   input wire [21:0]x; 
   input wire [21:0]y;
   wire [21:0]z;

   genvar i;

   generate
   for(i=0; i<22; i=i+1)
            begin
            confrontatore t(z[i],x[i],y[i]);
            end
   endgenerate

   assign r = & z;

endmodule
```

commutatore :

```
module commutatore (uscita_commutatore, alpha);

   output wire [2:0]uscita_commutatore;
   input wire alpha;
   reg [2:0]temp;

   initial
   begin
   case (alpha)
        1'b0 : assign temp = 3;
        1'b1 : assign temp = 4;
   endcase
   end   

   assign uscita_commutatore = temp;        

endmodule
```

prova:

```
module prova();

   reg [21:0]in1;
   reg [21:0]in2;
   wire [2:0]uscita;

   wire uscita_comparatore;

   comparatore c(uscita_comparatore, in1, in2);

   commutatore C(uscita, uscita_comparatore);

   initial
   begin
   in1 = 14;

    $dumpfile("prova.vcd");
    $dumpvars;

    $monitor("\n in1 %d in2 %d -> uscita %d uscita_comparatore %d \n", in1, in2, uscita, uscita_comparatore);

   #25 in2 = 14;

   #100 $finish;
   end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in `commutatore`. You are using `initial`, which means the procedural block is only executed at time 0. At time 0, the input `alpha` is `1'bx`, meaning temp is not assigned to anything. Instead of `initial`, use `always @*` which will execute the procedural block every time `alpha` changes.

Generally you should not assign statements in procedural blocks. It is legal Verilog however it is often the source of design bugs and synthesis support is limited.

```
always @*
begin
  case (alpha)
    1'b0 : temp = 3;
    1'b1 : temp = 4;
    default: temp = 3'bx; // <-- optional : to catch known to unknown transitions
  endcase
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting 4 as you expect for an output is because your `commutatore` uses an `initial` block with `assign` statements in it when you wanted an `always @*` block to perform the combinational logic to get `temp`. `initial` blocks only fire once at the beginning of a simulation, while you want continuous assignment to act as combinational logic. Also, the `assign` statements in the block are not needed, they only make the simulation behave improperly for your purposes (typically, you will never need to use `assign` inside another block (`initial`,`always`,etc) as this has another meaning than simply set x to y.

For example, you really want something like this:

```
always @(*) begin
  case (alpha)
    1'b0: temp = 3'd3;
    1'b1: temp = 3'd4;
  endcase
end
```

Also, Verilog already has a build XNOR primative so your `confrontatore` is not needed, you can use `xnor` instead.